# Update url file on multiple pcs & folders

Tags: batch-file, url, vbscript

Our corporate office where I work has locked down our use of GPO to push out things and we also utilize Kixtart but it doesn't work unless the user is an admin so I have to find another way to do this.

Basically we have a .url file on either the Public Desktop or the specific user account. I am hoping to find a script that will search not only the public desktop and replace the file but also individual users files.

Here's the working script! Thanks wOxxOm for helping.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "Citrix XenApp - Applications.url"') do copy /Y "\\server\hostshare\Citrix XenApp - Applications.url" "%%F"
```

PSExec script (note the -w for working directory)

```
psexec -w c:\users \\pc -u domain\username -p password -n 3 "\\server\shortcutchange.bat"
```

Comment: I'm running it through psexec but it doesn't seem to work correctly. My guess is it's not reading the command for some reason right. I have this in a batch file and when I psexec it the screen scrolls with the copy command (which shows it successful) but it never stops. I've tried things like `dir c:\ /b /s "Citrix XenApp - Applications.url"` but it doesn't work. I need it really just to search c:\users

Comment: `dir` command inside the batch file is executed in a current working directory of the target computer which is probably not what you want. Try explicitly specifying it: `dir /b /s "%PUBLIC%\Citrix XenApp - Applications.url"` or use `c:\users` instead of `%public%`.

Comment: If I change it to `dir /b /s c:\users "Citrix XenApp - Applications.url"` it does the scrolling thing as well. do I need to add onto the script so it's searching c:\users for the url file somehow?

Comment: `dir /b /s "c:\users\Citrix XenApp - Applications.url"` also put `DO (` on the same line as `for`.

Comment: The file path is correct, I just shortened it for here. I've updated the main code above and some more details of what's going on now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95478/discussion-between-mackman-and-woxxom).

Comment: There's no `%%a` inside the loop body that's why `copy` just puts the file in one directory. Should be `copy/y "sourcefile" "%%a"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working script! Thanks wOxxOm for helping.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "Citrix XenApp - Applications.url"') do copy /Y "\\server\hostshare\Citrix XenApp - Applications.url" "%%F"
```

PSExec script (note the -w for working directory)

```
psexec -w c:\users \\pc -u domain\username -p password -n 3 "\\server\shortcutchange.bat"
```